# how to write comments in cgo arguments

Tags: go, ffi, cgo

I have the following cgo arguments and I want to annotate lines with things like `// this checks for 32bit` etc. how can I do that without getting? `invalid flag in #cgo CFLAGS: //`

```
// #cgo CFLAGS: -I./depend/ -I./depend/src/
// #cgo 386 amd64p32 arm armbe mips mipsle mips64p32 mips64p32le ppc s390 sparc CFLAGS: -D32bit=1 // 32 bit
// #cgo amd64 arm64 arm64be ppc64 ppc64le mips64 mips64le s390x sparc64 CFLAGS: -D64bit=1 // 64 bit
// #cgo arm64be armbe mips mips64 mips64p32 ppc s390 s390x sparc sparc64 CFLAGS: -DBIGENDIAN=1 // big endian
// #include "example.c"
import "C"
```

Comment: What have you tried? The preamble is parsed as C, so c-style comments should work correctly.

Comment: I tried just adding `// my comment` and I get `invalid flag in #cgo CFLAGS: //`

Comment: Please show the _exact_ source you are using. Since the comment is what is being process, you need to comment the text twice (or use c-style block comments for one level to make it more obvious).

Comment: @JimB Edited with the *exact* comment

Comment: `#cgo` directives (as well as others directives) are not C source, you can't put C comments on the same line. (not to mention, go style guidelines prefer comments to precede their subjects anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```golang
// // comment in the comment
// #cgo CFLAGS: -I./depend/ -I./depend/src/
// // 32 bit
// #cgo 386 amd64p32 arm armbe mips mipsle mips64p32 mips64p32le ppc s390 sparc CFLAGS: -D32bit=1
// // 64 bit
// #cgo amd64 arm64 arm64be ppc64 ppc64le mips64 mips64le s390x sparc64 CFLAGS: -D64bit=1
// // big endian
// #cgo arm64be armbe mips mips64 mips64p32 ppc s390 s390x sparc sparc64 CFLAGS: -DBIGENDIAN=1
// #include "example.c"
import "C"
```